# How to remove obj from array Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have to arrays of obj (obj's are the same in those arrays , with the same props). I want to removed all obj's with the same name that can be found in `filesToRemove` from array `files`. Code below throw an error: `Uncaught TypeError: files.splice is not a function` - what I'm doing wrong? For testing purpose I used `delete files[j];`, but it does nothing. Thanks!

```
var filesToRemove = [
{ name: "SCO Bike Contessa 730 a.jpg"},
{ name: "SCO Bike Contessa 730.jpg"}]

var files= [
{ name: "SCO Bike Aspect 930.jpg" },
{ name: "SCO Bike Contessa 730 a.jpg"},
{ name: "SCO Bike Contessa 730.jpg"}]

remove(filesToRemove, files)
function remove(filesToRemove, files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < filesToRemove.length; i++) {
        if (filesToRemove[i].name) {
            for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {
                if (files[j].name == filesToRemove[i].name) {
                    if (j > -1) {
                        files.splice(j, 1);
                    }
                    //delete files[j];
                }
            }
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: Pretty hard to tell without knowing what you're calling the function with

Comment: I agree with @CertainPerformance that it is very hard to tell without the input of the function

Comment: I'm sorry, I always forget about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some of JS's  array methods.

```
var files = [{name: 'foo.txt'}, {name: 'bar.txt'}, {name: 'baz.txt'}]
var files_to_remove = [{name: 'bar.txt'}]

files = files.map(file => {
  var found = files_to_remove.some(o => o.name == file.name)
  return found ? null : file
})

console.log(files)
```

https://jsbin.com/pubirawoqe/edit?js,console

jQuery version:
https://jsbin.com/kejacezuta/edit?js,console

Comment: Instead of using `filter` to check for existance, use `some`: `var found = files_to_remove.some(o => o.name == file.name);`. In this case `found` will be a boolean.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir great tip for simplying the code a bit!

Comment: maybe this is a stupid question, but with javascipt and jquery I'm having short time. The 'map' comes from pure javascript or jquery? I receive such an error: TypeError: files.map is not a function, at Object.<anonymous> (create:569), at u (VM240 jquery.min.js:2) .....

Comment: @szkut It's pure js. are you using jQuery? if so you want to use jQuery map - https://jsbin.com/kejacezuta/edit?js,console

Comment: Jquery version works great - thanks!! I always thought that by adding the jquery library, I can actually decide what syntax to use pure js or jquery. This error shows me that it isn't always like that. I need to go further and google it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var filesToRemove = [ { name: "SCO Bike Contessa 730 a.jpg"}, { name: "SCO Bike Contessa 730.jpg"} ]
var files= [ { name: "SCO Bike Aspect 930.jpg" }, { name: "SCO Bike Contessa 730 a.jpg"}, { name: "SCO Bike Contessa 730.jpg"}]

const result = files.filter(x => !filesToRemove.some(y => y.name == x.name))
console.log(result)
```

Filter would filter the initial array by making sure that its values are **not** in the filesToRemove array via the `!some`

Comment: I really dont understand what is wrong with my code and scripts here I got the same error as at second answer ...TypeError: files.filteris not a function,... I', working via chrome - Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official version) (64-bit)

Comment: Make sure you have correctly specified the data ... your question data for example is wrong since you have an extra `}` ... will fix it in a sec there. Fixed your input in your question.